# drawing the percentage of a value in canvas. Math-Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry

I have a math-programming problem. 
I am trying to calculate the percentage of the availability and draw a complete a circle that represents the value.

So I have all customer-service members "allMemebrs" and I have the available as "availableMemebrs"
I calculated it like this:

```
var percentage = (100 * availableMemebrs) / allMemebrs;
```

and now I want to draw a circle in canvas javascript:

```
ctx.arc(50, 50, 20, 1.5 * Math.PI, percentage * 2 * Math.PI);
```

If I start the circle from 0 that means:

```
ctx.arc(50, 50, 20, 0, percentage * 2 * Math.PI);
```

it will draw it correctly, but the problem is that I want to draw it from 1.5 * PI and that is the problem.

I am a bit lost. Anybody can help?

Comment: allMemebrs or allMembers? What about availableMemebrs?

Comment: Hardcode percentage to 0,5 and see if it draws halfcircle. Repeat step for other values

Comment: "does this ... will draw the correct part of the circle?" Didn't you test it before?

Comment: @chade_ I don't know how. the percentage I am getting are a bit hard to test. I am just doing right now.

Comment: @TomaszBubała Ooh thanks, that will help

Comment: It did not unfortunately, it draws 3 quarters instead of 2 @TomaszBubała

Comment: please see the edit

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc), the syntax for drawing an arc is follwing:

```
ctx.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle [, anticlockwise]);
```

Your `endAngle` is fine only if your `startAngle` would be **0**, as [Faly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7446273/faly) suggested in his answer.

Edit after comment:

You can set your default offset from starting point.

```
var offset = 1.5 * Math.PI;
ctx.arc(50, 50, 20, offset, (percentage * 2 * Math.PI) + offset);
```

Comment: exactly, that is my problem. I do it correctly when it is from 0 to 2 * PI. 
but I have to draw it from 1.5 * PI and this is the problem

Comment: Ooh Cool thanks, it does solve the problem. I have tried to add a custom value. but I did not think about adding the offset in this way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your percentage calculation is wrong:

```
var percentage = availableMemebrs / allMemebrs ;
ctx.arc(50, 50, 20, 0, percentage * 2 * Math.PI);
```

Comment: Code-only answers prefixed by "Try this" are not welcome on SO. Consider adding a minimal explanation on the solution, how it addresses the problem/question and why it's supposed to work. You're not answering only for OP, but for all future visitors with a similar problem. Quite often, this type of answers are copy/paste from duplicate questions. You really want to set yourself apart from this type of answer. Happy coding!